# Pass "content-projection" into recursive NGTemplateOutlet component?

Tags: angular, recursion, angular2-template

I am trying to create a recursive component for a node-tree using NgTemplateOutlet.

I'm stuck at the part where I need the html that was passed into the component at top-level to be shown inside my recursive component..

I am basing my recursive component on [this article](https://alligator.io/angular/reusable-components-ngtemplateoutlet/), and [this StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/alligator-ng-template-outlet?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts).

**app.component.html**

```
<wt-nested-list [nodes]="topNodeTree">
  <div *nestedListNode="let node">
    <h1>{{ node.nodeName }}</h1>
  </div>
</wt-nested-list>
```

**nested-list.component.html**

```
<div class="wt-nested-list">

<ng-container *ngFor="let node of nodes">
  <!-- node -->
  <div class="wt-nested-list__node">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="nodeTemplate; context: {$implicit: node}"></ng-container>
    <!-- child nodes of node -->
    <ng-container *ngIf="node.children">
      <wt-nested-list>
        ???
      </wt-nested-list>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</ng-container>

</div>
```

How do I ge the the custom html ( `<div *nestedListNode= ...etc` ) from **app.component.html** to also be placed into the recursive part inside **wt-nested-list.component.html** ? (indicated by **???**)

**Here is a www.stackblitz.com example that might help explain my problem**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wt9f4x

Comment: < wt-nested-list [nodes]="node.children" >< /wt-nested-list>

Comment: That won't give me custom html inside tho like it does on the app.component.html tho..

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz demo for this?

Comment: @yurzui yep, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wt9f4x

Comment: @yurzui omg.. thank you so much!!! Could you post this as an answer so you can get the vote? Also, can I marry you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would solve this by defining optional `@Input` property that I will pass for nested component:

**nested-list.component.ts**

```
class NestedListComponent {

  @Input() template: TemplateRef<any>;

  @ContentChild( NestedListNodeDirective, { read: TemplateRef } ) nodeTemplate;
```

Now, in template we need to make sure that at least one of these template exists:

**nested-list.component.html**

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="nodeTemplate || template; context: ..."></ng-container>
...
<wt-nested-list [nodes]="node.children" [template]="nodeTemplate || template">
</wt-nested-list>
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aygx5l?file=src%2Fapp%2Fnested-list%2Fnested-list.component.html)**